# Mapping Link and Image data types using Data Exchange Framework

Tags: data-exchange-framework

We are working on importing data from XML feed into Sitecore using Data Exchange Framework(DEF). The General Link Field has the right url in raw data but rendered data(Content Editor) field is empty.

Is there a specific value reader and writer for mapping to Sitecore Image, General Link field types?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no specific value reader and writer for mapping to Sitecore Image or General Link field types.